# Syntactic role of "de" in "donnez-moi de ne devoir qu’à Vous cette joie"

Tags: syntaxe

The question is on *de* as highlighted in this passage from the 'Alissa's Journal' section of *La porte étroite* by André Gide.

> Je le sens bien, je le sens à ma tristesse, que le sacrifice n’est pas consommé dans mon cœur. Mon Dieu, donnez-moi **de** ne devoir qu’à Vous cette joie que lui seul me faisait connaître.

**QUESTION**

Why is *de* there?

**BACKGROUND**

In the sentence *lui* refers to a particular person.

I am looking for a way to account for the *de* in the passage so I would know when to expect or place a *de* similarly.

By accounting I mean things like the following.  These are random guesses, and I give them not because I think they are right, but only to illustrate the kind of explanation I would like to receive.

1. *de* is part of the verbal expression *donner de*.  But this seems unlikely because I cannot find *donner de* in dictionaries.
2. *de devoir* forms a sort of partitive.  *devoir* is the infinitive, meaning *to owe* or (if it reads better) *owing*.  If calling it a partitive sounds crackpot, I may say that the idea was to assimilate *donner de devoir* to things like *donner de son temps* and *donner du sens à*.
3. *de devoir* is the infinitive.  But the French equivalent of *going to him was a good idea* or *after saying good bye he...* (I won't try to put them in French) does not seem to have a *de* in the infinitive.  So I would want to know when an infinitive needs a *de*, and when not.

I can only tag this question as 'syntax' as yet.  Once I am told what *de* is in the sentence, I may be able to tag better.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a prayer to God: Give me only having to owe You alone for the joy he alone made me know. When you pray, you say: God, please give me [whatever]. In English also, it is a bit awkward.

Comment: It’s almost like the notion of “la force” is being omitted in this strange (to me) structure: ... “Donnez-moi [la force] de [faire qqch].” ….. “God, please grant me the strength to be beholden/give thanks to You and You alone for [whatever/everything].”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it a preposition. [Meaning II - A - 1 - a - β](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) in the TLF entry. "*De* introduit le complément d'objet second de verbes transitifs indirects."

This *de* is not specific to *donner*. I say that because of the existence of parallel structures like this:

> Je lui demande son avis.
>   
> Je lui conseille la salade.
>   
> Je lui promets un cadeau.
>
> Je lui demande de venir.
>   
> Je lui conseille de manger plus vite.
>   
> Je lui promets d'écrire un autre roman.

Here, *de* introduces a verbal clause "filling the role" of a noun phrase. You are equally free to ask for [determiner + noun] or for [*de* + infinitive]. There is nothing inherent about *donner* that demands *de* ; rather, it's the verbal complement that demands *de*.

An alternative analysis is that there are (at least) two verbs that look like *donner* but have different argument structures. One has the structure *donner qqch. à qqn.* and takes an NP for the direct object. The other has the structure *donner à qqn. de faire* and takes a VP. Naturally, this has the possibly undesirable consequence that we need to posit nearly duplicate lexical entries for many verbs.

But whether we analyze *de* as attached to the complement or to the verb, at some level each verb must define its semantic relationship with a verbal complement (if it takes one). While the general function of [*de* + infinitive] is to designate an action to be performed, the question of by whom and in what capacity is settled on a verb-by-verb basis. For example, for *demander*, the complement is an action to be performed by the other object, but for *promettre*, it's to be performed by the subject.

Comment: Thank you, particularly for expressly considering the two syntactic possibilities (*de* attaching to the one or the other thing). It would be easy for someone (or even some academy) to make a facile choice between the two and just insist on it, but it wouldn't be convincing without some basis, e.g. tracing to some earlier form where *de* indisputably attached to the one and not the other.

Comment: Indeed. I had some good profs and textbooks who would do that — even though sooner or late most would eventually argue the side they didn't like into implied ridiculousness, they usually stated the sides clearly enough that as a student I felt I could make up my own mind. It's been too long since those linguistics courses for me to really argue for one or the other here... but one thing to observe is that this *de* certainly has nothing to do with the verb phrase itself, since infinitive subjects have no *de*, so at a minimum we have to say its presence is triggered by the verbal context...

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the verbal expression *donner à quelqu'un de faire quelque chose* meaning *allowing someone to do something*.  (It is in some [dictionnaries](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/donner/26437/locution?q=donner#154728).)

Comment: Indeed. So it's a preposition that introduces an infinitive clause. *Donnez-moi de* is rather uncommon and sounds typical of religious vernacular.

Comment: Well, here, with God, I'd say it's Give me. One prays to God to be given something. Not allow.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Yes it does sound like something one would ask God, or at least someone with a lot of power (a king, perhaps a judge or a religious leader). For ordinary uses from human to human, _"Ordonnez-moi de"_ or _"Permettez-moi de"_ seem more likely than _"Donnez-moi de"_.

Answer (score 2):

Maj-Britt Mosegaard Hansen (according to her excellent *The Structure of Modern Standard French*) 
would regard the *de* here not as a preposition but simply as an infinitive marker. That’s because a noun phrase can be substituted for the infinitival clause, without requiring *de*.

Not all infinitival clauses require an infinitive marker but when the infinitival clause serves as a direct object, as here, the “default” is that it requires the infinitive marker *de*.

Answer (score 1):

Cette réponse vise à faire le point sur une question peut être pas si difficile mais pour laquelle on ne trouve pas des références suffisamment explicites, cela étant surtout la source de l'ennui à mon avis. Elle reprend le travail d'autres fournisseurs de réponses et elle commence par une familiarisation avec la sémantique de l'expression (par des exemples), ce qui me semble essentiel à l'identification du verbe. (Les exemples sans référence à un dictionnaire sont de mon invention.)

C'est une expression verbale courante au passif en tournure impersonnelle, on la trouve dans le parler de personne qui y ont été suffisamment exposées et elle n'est donc pas spécialement littéraire ;  elle n'a absolument aucune implication religieuse ; elle signifie simplement « ménager des circonstances favorables pour (qqc) », « faire les choses de  sorte que soit possible (qqc) », et autres variantes.

> au passif, tournure impersonnelle, courant

- Il lui a été donné étant jeune d'avoir un accès facile à une importante bibliothèque, celle de son père.
- Il a été donné à cette firme d'échapper à la charge de plusieurs impôts, d'où son succès.
- Il n'est pas donné à n'importe qui de parler quatre langues sans accent.
- **ex 1** (TLFi) Mais j'ai remarqué une disposition analogue chez toutes les personnes véritablement supérieures qu'il m'a été donné de fréquenter.
- **ex 2** (TLFi, Gide, journal) Sans doute ne me sera-t-il pas donné d'assister à la restauration des valeurs morales pour laquelle il y aurait eu joie à vivre...

> impératif

- Seigneur, donnez-nous  de surmonter ces difficultés avant qu'il ne soit trop tard. (prière)
- Donnez-lui de pouvoir élever volaille et lapins à sa façon et elle vous fera des terrines délicieuses.

> actif, moins courant

- Il leur a donné d'avoir un bon départ dans la vie mais rien de plus.
- Cette nouvelle attraction touristique a donné à l'hôtellerie dans la région de connaitre un essort remarquable mais qui n'a pas eu de suite.

Cet usage de « donner » tombe sous le coup du sens suivant du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner)

> « I. Emploi trans.
>   A. [Implique une idée de libéralité] Faire en sorte que quelqu'un ait quelque chose.
>   2. P. ext. Mettre (quelqu'un) en possession (de quelque chose); mettre au pouvoir (de quelqu'un).
>   b) Accorder.
>  ».

On trouve sous cette définition, en plus de la construction discutée, les constructions des exemple suivants, dans lesquels l'objet n'est plus introduit par « de », lequel n'est utilisé que lorsque il est question d'une proposition infinitive en objet (voir réponse de [user **justerman**](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34074/17649)).

**ex TLFi sans prop. infinitive**

- Orso se hâta de donner *son assentiment* à ce projet.
- La clause portant que les époux se marient sans communauté, ne donne point à la femme *de droit d'administrer ses biens*, ni *d'en percevoir les fruits* ...
- Jamais par le destin il ne sera donné À ton Iphigénie *un jour plus fortuné*.

Il faut rapprocher cette acception du TLFi de celle du Larousse (en ligne) pour la soit disant expression [donner à quelqu'un (de)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/donner/26437/locution) ;

> lui fournir la possibilité, l'occasion de, le mettre dans une situation où il doit 
>   ou peut faire quelque chose

- (*exemple du Larousse sous cette acception*) Le sort lui a donné de réaliser tous ses projets.

Si on compare les deux définitions et les exemples trouvés dans le TLFi (**ex 1, 2,** et **ex TLFi sans prop. infinitive** ) on s'aperçoit de plusieurs choses ;

- La partie finale de la définition du TLFi n'est qu'une généralisation qui serait trop spécifique et qui doit aller dans le sens de celle du Larousse pour que les exemples soient justifiables (**ex 1 et ex 2** en particulier).
- Avec cet ajustement (accorder, fournir la possibilité, mettre dans une situation, etc.), tous les exemples sont rassemblés, fidèles à cette définition.
- Cette définition est celle d'un verbe : **donner *qqc.* à *qqn.***, *ou* **donner à *qqu.* de *faire qqc*.**) et il ne s'agit pas d'une véritable locution figée mais d'une construction, où, pour rejoindre ce qui est avancé par justerman la préposition « de » est utilisée pour introduire une proposition infinitive.

On peut adapter les termes définissants à un des exemples et de même pour les autres ;

```
Jamais par le destin il n'aura été accordé  À ton Iphigénie un jour plus fortuné.
Jamais par le destin il n'aura été fait en sorte que ton Iphigénie ait un jour plus fortuné.
```

Je peux maintenant essayer de clarifier certaines des questions soulevées dans les trois interrogations finales de la question.

1. It seems unlikely that "de" should be part of a verbal expression "donner de", but it is in fact more or less the case, at least insofar as we speak of a construction, and at that, a construction followed by an infinitive ("donner de la tête dans un mur" is something else) ; you do see that in the définition from the Larousse ; the word « de » being between parentheses is the expression of the fact that there are two constructions for the verb ; of course, this is a blurred definition in the Larousse and what is from my point of view a lacuna of not making that specific in the TLFi, does not help.
2. The possibility of a partitive should be discarded without the least doubt by now. In any case let's consider that for a partitive, we must have as you justly point out a concept that lends itself to the taking out of parts of what it embodies, (le temps, le sens); a verb,  "devoir" for instance, is a relation (complex, beyond our full understanding) and to obtain variants of such a concept there are only adverbs; we can, by the use of suitable adverbs placed by the verb produce a great number of variants of the relation expressed by the verb itself but never by using partitives.
3. The error in considering that infinitive without « de » as a possible explanation of a difference in meaning comes from forgetting that the cases you take into account are those of infinitival clauses the function of which in the sentence is subject of a verb or adverbial complement, and not, as in what concerns us, an object. As pertains to this word and the possibility of not considering it a preposition (justerman) but a "marker" I think the word makes salient a grammatical function and not the grammatical nature of an element, that appearing to be so as in other functions the word is not needed; however, I would agree that one is dealing here with a use of  prepositions in which they have lost much or all of any semantical value they may normally have.